# What to do with EventHandlers in a ControlTemplate defined in a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, event-handling

This question is more about neat programming along the MVVM lines rather than a 'how-do-I-get-this-to-work' one. 
I wanted to keep all the `ControlTemplates` for my `DataTemplates` in a separate `ResourceDictionary` file, for clarity. So, in the main Window it looks like this, e.g:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localm:MusicSystem}">
    <Control Template="{StaticResource MusicSystemTemplate}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, the ControlTemplate for this very Class contains a `ListBox` which is supposed to react to certain events - have some handlers, as here:

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MusicSystemTemplate">
    <StackPanel ... >
        <ListBox x:Name="SystemListBox" ...
                 PreviewMouseMove="SystemListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
                 PreviewMouseDown="SystemListBox_PreviewMouseDown"
                 MouseEnter="SystemListBox_MouseEnter"
                 MouseLeave="SystemListBox_MouseLeave">
            <!-- More ListBox stuff here --> 
        </ListBox>
        <!-- More other stuff here -->
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

For now I'm keeping this template in the XAML of the main Window, and the handlers in its code behind, but that's not what I want. If it was a Button, I'd create a command and bind it one way or the other. But since it's a ListBox, I'm unfortunately deprived of that possibility. I wouldn't like to resort to the code behind of the ResourceDictionary, because this is not what they are for. Is there a neat and not overly verbose way around it? Or maybe there is something wrong with declaring handlers within a Template altogether?

Comment: Events are `View` specific, if you want to use the `Templates` in multiple views you are going to have to use a binding method instead, e.g. `AttachedProperty`, `Behaviours` etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use attached behaviors for this. They can either be [behaviors attached using Blend's Interactivity assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725476.aspx), or just [attached properties which add and remove event handlers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) when their values are changed.

Overview: [Behaviors in WPF introduction](http://www.jayway.com/2013/03/20/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction/).